# How to keep loudness of SFX with TV mix?

Tags: mixing, sfx, television

TV mix is always restricted with limited peak level(eg. -12dbfs). When I put a limiter on it,all my sfx got fatten.What can be done to keep the loudness and transparency of SFX(gun, explosion, punch) in TV mix?

Comment: Can you just lower the level of your SFX before it hits the limiter?

Comment: Of course I can, but if I do this, all sfx will lose punchy. When I watched True Detective on TV I found out that those gunshots still sound in your face and the overall dynamic range was not so much.

Comment: Put a limiter just on the SFX channel and lower the output of the SFX limiter or the overall post-limiter channel volume.

Comment: You should check delivery specs from the TV broadcaster as it is now common to have a loudness target level rather than a limited peak level.

Comment: i would go V on the EQ and compress the 2 bands alone to control the energy and let the mid freqs just do their thing. This will create the loudness effect but with everything being under control, when you want in your face and loud stuff, you go no mids-lo mids, just loudness chart.

Comment: you mean using an multiband compressor and just compress low and hi?

Comment: yes compress hard, bring the make up to the first level , arround 8 db reduction would be ok . start the bass compression from arround 100 , and high from arround 8k leave the mids untouched, or touch them if you think they need it , but not for the same reason.

Comment: please forgive me for my bad English. What is the meaning of ‘bring the make up to the first level’? Do you mean set the make up gain equal to original level after compression? For example,  if I set the compresion range below 100hz is -8db in C4, then the gain of this range is similar to pre compress signal?(like +8?) and do I need to make a V shape of the mid before compresion?

Answer (score 1):

Look up Ebu R-128 you need to be using the 'LUFS' scale for delivery. Different normalizations are required depending what continent you're on.

Answer (score 0):

This is not (necessarily) a case where simply plopping a plugin on the track will achieve your goal. This is much more a case of learning what TYPES of sounds will punch through a TV mix (and TV speaker), and learning the secret of "bigness", which is an incredibly difficult discipline to learn, IMHO.

In short, lots of sound editors will rely on cutting at loud volumes on full-range speakers and even pump huge amounts of low frequency energy through subwoofers because, hey, it makes everything sound BIGGER! But when you fold all of that down to stereo and play it back much lower on a set of crappy speakers, guess what? It all sounds really SMALL.

Maybe you're already working in stereo on smaller speakers. If so, that's an excellent starting point. A very wise man told me once, "if you can make it sound big on small crappy speakers, it will sound big nearly anywhere". That advice has served me well over the years.

So, I believe it's less about the limiters and more about your choices.